# What is the derivation of the dot product formula?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors, proof-explanation

What is a mathematical explanation of the connection between:
(1) projecting vector a onto vector b and multiplying the projected length of a with the length of vector b, and
(2) the sum of the products of the equivalent components of the two vectors?

I realise there is a duality between a 2-dimensional vector and a 1x2 matrix, which can be used to explain the computation of the dot product. But I have not seen a satisfactory mathematical derivation, and was wondering whether there is another, simpler mathematical explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's start with the geometrical definition$$\vec a\cdot \vec b = ab\cos\theta$$
Also, suppose that we have an orthonormal basis $\{\hat e_i\}$. Then $$\vec a=\sum_i a_i\hat e_i\\\vec b=\sum_i b_i\hat e_i$$
Now using the geometrical definition, if two of the basis vectors are the same
$$\hat e_i\cdot \hat e_i=e_ie_i\cos 0=1$$and if two vectors are different
$$\hat e_i\cdot \hat e_j=e_ie_j\cos\frac{\pi}2=0$$
Then $$\vec a \cdot\vec b=\vec a\cdot\left(\sum_i b_i\hat e_i\right)=\sum_i(\vec a\cdot \hat e_i)b_i=\sum_ia_i b_i$$

Comment: Thank you so much!